# Issue restoring KMS encrypted backup from S3 to RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am attempting to backup a database from a non-AWS instance, push to S3, and then restore that database on an RDS instance. I've successfully pushed the file to S3 with server-side encryption, but I am running into a problem when trying to restore said database on the RDS instance.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Object metadata (x-amz-key) incomplete, cannot decrypt the given S3 object.

And here is the code that I'm using (with private info removed) to write the object to S3 and restore on RDS:

**Powershell**:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName my-S3-bucket -Key "my_test_database.bak" -File C:\somepath\my_test_database.bak -ServerSideEncryption aws:kms -ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId "abcde012-abcd-0123-ef89-9876543210cd" -ProfileName default
```

**SQL Server** (on RDS instance):

```
EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[rds_restore_database] @restore_db_name = 'my_test_database',
    @S3_arn_to_restore_from = N'arn:aws:s3:::my-S3-bucket/my_test_database.bak',
    @KMS_master_key_arn = N'arn:aws:kms:region:0123456789:key/abcde012-abcd-0123-ef89-9876543210cd';
```

I'm wondering if there is something I could have missed when setting up the IAM or generating the encryption keys. As far as I can tell, my code to push to S3 and restore the database are identical to the AWS docs.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS supports two types of encryption for objects stored in the bucket: Server Side Encryption (SSE) and Client Side Encryption (CSE). If you plan to use the encrypted SQL Server restore option, the backup files **must be Client Side Encrypted**.

In cases where you simply upload an SQL backup into an S3 bucket with SSE configured for the bucket, trying to restore from that backup file will fail, and the AWS RDS server instance will throw an exception: "Object metadata (x-amz-key) incomplete, cannot decrypt the given S3 object ..."

Comment: I attempted to implement client-side encryption, but it seems to only corrupt the backup when I try restoring in RDS with the KMS arn. How would I go about encrypting it so that the backup can be decrypted with KMS and restore successfully? Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Your reply help me out to sort what was going on.  In my case I removed encryption from S3 temporary bucket and also removed the @kms_master_key_arn key from my backup command.